# MS SQL 2008 cpu usage

Tags: sql-server-2008, cpu-usage

My application uses MS SQL server 2008 and it is hosted in a Windows 2003 Enterprise Server SP2 (32 bit) 2-CPU 8 gig Ram VM machine. The application has 2  or more windows services.One of those service access the DB frequently. When the load of the DB is set 65k or something , the CPU usage hikes upto 75-95% and it doesnt seem to reduce until unless the service is stopped.
This issue we have not faced in Oracle 10 g, with the same application and same load.

How to reduce the cpu usage ? 
Is there something I need to do with the application code or with the SQL server.?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Priya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it accesses the database, is it logging in, doing it's work, and then logging out? If so, see if you can retain the same connection rather than tearing down each time.

To see if it is an issue with the work it is doing, run SQL Profiler against the server and look for high read counts, high cpu count or long duration queries.